# Kafka topics to Spark Streaming DStream, how to get a Json

Tags: json, scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, dstream

I'm trying to get the information from a Kafka Topic with Spark Streaming and then parse the json I get in the topic.
In order to get the topic in a DStream I use a stringReader and then I use foreach to get every RDD from the DStream:

```
myRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

In order to convert myRDD into a json (when I print myRDD the format for a json is correct) and extract two fields I need, I've tried to use json4s and tried this:

```
val jsonEvent = Json.parse(myRDD)
val srcIp = (jsonEvent / "src_ip")
val dstIp =  (jsonEvent / "dst_ip")
```

I've also tried to use json4s this way:

```
val jsonEvent = parse(myRDD).asInstanceOf[JObject]
val srcIp = jsonEvent / "src_ip"
```

But it's not working correctly either.

This is the output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: rg.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.parse$default$3()Z
```

These are the versions I'm using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>json4s-native_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
    <artifactId>json4s-jackson_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I think that the problem is that I don't understand how exactly I can transform each record in the RDD to a json object to parse it. Can someone please explain it more deeply to me so I can understand how it works? 
Is my code correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Spark provides you API's to read the input JSON to a Dataset/Dataframe.

If you are reading JSON from a file. You can read by using the `SparkSession` `read().json()` method

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Test App").master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> inputfileDataset = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
            .json("C:\path-to-file\inputfile.json");
```

If you are reading from KAFKA Streams. You can iterate through the each RDD by converting them to `List` of `String`s and then convert them to Dataset/Dataframe

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class,
                String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

JavaDStream<String> inputJsonStream = directKafkaStream.map(rdd -> {
    return rdd._2;
});

inputJsonStream.foreachRDD(inputRDD -> {
    SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(inputRDD.context().getConf());
    List<String> strings = inputRDD.collect();
    strings.forEach(x -> {
        Dataset<Row> inputDataset = spark.read().option("multiLine",true).option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(inputRDD);
        inputDataset.printSchema();
});
```

For querying the Dataset/Dataframe you may use the `Select()` function on the Dataset and then transform it into the datatype you want.